# How to get a list of the input and output formats in ImageMagick API?

Tags: encoding, imagemagick, webassembly

I am tinkering with the [browser / wasm ImageMagick API](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm), and it has a `MagickFormat` module [here](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm/blob/f395a984061a6ce7fa6a73e0f5dce9bfd1cbcb49/src/enums/magick-format.ts#L7) which looks like this essentially:

```
export declare enum MagickFormat {
    Unknown = "UNKNOWN",
    ThreeFr = "3FR",
    ThreeG2 = "3G2",
    ThreeGp = "3GP",
    A = "A",
    Aai = "AAI",
    Ai = "AI",
    Apng = "APNG",
    Art = "ART",
    Arw = "ARW",
    Ashlar = "ASHLAR",
    Avi = "AVI",
    Avif = "AVIF",
    Avs = "AVS",
    B = "B",
    Bayer = "BAYER",
    Bayera = "BAYERA",
    Bgr = "BGR",
    Bgra = "BGRA",
    Bgro = "BGRO",
    Bmp = "BMP",
    Bmp2 = "BMP2",
    Bmp3 = "BMP3",
    Brf = "BRF",
    C = "C",
    Cal = "CAL",
    Cals = "CALS",
    Canvas = "CANVAS",
    Caption = "CAPTION",
    Cin = "CIN",
    Cip = "CIP",
    Clip = "CLIP",
    Cmyk = "CMYK",
    Cmyka = "CMYKA",
    Cr2 = "CR2",
    Cr3 = "CR3",
    ...
```

Essentially it lists about ~260 formats, but *it doesn't say which ones are allowed as **input** and which ones are allowed as **output**.* I tried to convert a PNG to CR2 but the wasm API failed with:

```
Error: NoEncodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `CR2' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1409
```

I knew this would fail because I read it on some random website I can't remember, that CR2 is the Canon camera raw format, and they can only take it as *input* and use it to generate more simple outputs like JPG/PNG/etc.. But my question is, what exactly are the allowed input and output formats for ImageMagick? How can I figure that out? Is there a way to list them somehow with the API (which I can then figure out to translate to the wasm API)? Ideally not a CLI example, but a source code API example I guess.

Do all those in `MagickFormat` get allowed as input formats? And only a subset as output formats? Or where can I find which are allowed for which? Oh and related, does it depend on the input what output is allowed? (Like, is it a matrix of "JPG can convert into X and Y but not Z, but PNG can convert into X and Z but not Y" sort of thing, or is it more simple than that?) I'm partially curious in this process if you have to create a list of one-to-many mappings for each input type to the possible outputs for that input, or of it's more generic than that.

Main goal: figure out what operations I am allowed to make.

I also saw the [`supportedFormats` property](https://github.com/dlemstra/magick-wasm/blob/f395a984061a6ce7fa6a73e0f5dce9bfd1cbcb49/src/magick.ts#L33), but I'm not sure that fully solves my problem.

Comment: Note your actual command failed because **ImageMagick** will not write CR2 files, or NEF/ARW or any other camera manufacturer raw files, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method I know is in Terminal:

```
identify -list format
```

and look for `r` for *read* and `w` for *write* in the second column:

**Output**

```
Format  Mode  Description
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3FR  r--   Hasselblad CFV/H3D39II (0.19.5-Release)
   3G2  r--   Media Container
   3GP  r--   Media Container
     A* rw+   Raw alpha samples
   AAI* rw+   AAI Dune image
    AI  rw-   Adobe Illustrator CS2
  APNG  rw+   Animated Portable Network Graphics
   ART* rw-   PFS: 1st Publisher Clip Art
   ARW  r--   Sony Alpha Raw Image Format
   ...
   ...
```

You can go from any format to any other - obviously providing the input source is readable and the output destination is writable. The *"all-encompassing, super format"* which can represent everything **ImageMagick** knows (e.g. 8/16/32/64-bit integer/float/complex samples, transparency, tens of channels, EXIF/XMP/IPTC data, GIF delays) is `MIFF` - so it essentially goes via that format from any input to any output.

---

Likewise, if you want to know what *"compositing/blending modes"* **ImageMagick** supports, you can use:

```
identify -list compose
```

**Output**

```
top
Blend
Blur
Bumpmap 
ChangeMask
Clear
ColorBurn
ColorDodge
...
...
```

---

The *"super command"* that tells you everything you could put after `identify -list`, i.e. *"give me a list of lists"*,  is:

```
identify -list list
```

**Output**

```
Align
Alpha
AutoThreshold
Boolean
Cache
Channel
Class
CLI
ClipPath
Coder
Color
Colorspace
Command
....
...
```

So you can get a list of all the available channel names, all the compression types, all the colourspaces, all the interpolation options, all gravity options, all the interlace options, all the possible virtual pixel types...